# Adding Header + Footer + Main Source messes layout

Tags: android, layout, alignment

I have header and footer code which i want to add with Relative Layout, but somewhere its messing. Please note the footer has to remain fixed at the bottom of screen despite of scroll of main source. Can someone guide on integration ?

[image]

After Vipul's suggestion :

[image]

Header :

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#0a2436"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" >
        </ImageView>
```

Footer :

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnManualLookup"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Activity"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/supportbutton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Support"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/messagebutton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Messages"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Main Source :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="18sp" 
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="13sp" 
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lefticons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/righticons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all three in one `relativelayout`.

Try following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/windowtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#0a2436"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" >
    </ImageView>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnManualLookup"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Activity"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/supportbutton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Support"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/messagebutton"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#092435"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="15dip"
                android:text="Messages"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/windowtitle"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="8dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#666666"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_summary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_entry_title"
                android:layout_below="@id/list_item_entry_title"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#666666"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lefticons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/righticons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but it gave horrible result

Comment: change height of your footer that is table layout to wrap_content.

Comment: Nop, still giving horrible result, i added screenshot

Comment: Can you post the exact layout you are using because it look perfect on my screen

Comment: Vipul, Code i posted is exact layout, only case is i was wanted to integrate "header" + "footer"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43401/discussion-between-vipul-mittal-and-user45678)

Comment: yet no results...same mess :(